# Using npm behind a firewall

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using npm behind a very strict corporate firewall. Basically I have to send a request for any port that has to be opened which usually takes 3-5 business days to complete. There is no proxy that I can use. Which ports do I have to open to make sure, npm can install all required packages?

Answer (score 0):

NPM communicates over http(s) with repositories. You may consider using [Nexus](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-2-npm-packages) on premises for proxying to official repositories.
Also check [this tutorial](http://wil.boayue.com/blog/2013/06/14/using-npm-behind-a-proxy/) how to setup proxy parameters for you local npm installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that was not really what I meant. I am running a npm script as a server and the problem is that the clients behind the firewall can not connect to the port I am using.